# Object Array Order by two Values in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i have the following object array

```
var parameter = "B001";
var my_array = [
                 {
                  "Shippment_out" : "2020-05-10",
                  "Batch" : "B001",
                  "Truck_No" : "ZB001"
                 },
                 {
                  "Shippment_out" : "2020-05-10",
                  "Batch" : "B002",
                  "Truck_No" : "ZB001"
                 },
                 {
                  "Shippment_out" : "2020-05-11",
                  "Batch" : "B001",
                  "Truck_No" : "ZB002"
                 },
                 {
                  "Shippment_out" : "2020-05-11",
                  "Batch" : "B002",
                  "Truck_No" : "ZB002"
                 },
               ]
```

i planning sort this by the parameter, if i pass batch no as B001 then the array should be sorted by B001 first then B002 together with earlier date first. in this case "2020-05-10".

likewise if i pass "B002" then "B002" then "B001". again earlier date first.

i tried `my_array.sort(function (a, b) {})` but not able to implement the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `sort` method, check a.Batch and b.Batch values.

if both values are same as required batch then sort it based on shipment.

if one of value is same as batch, then return accordingly.

```js
var my_array = [
  {
    Shippment_out: "2020-05-10",
    Batch: "B001",
    Truck_No: "ZB001"
  },
  {
    Shippment_out: "2020-05-10",
    Batch: "B002",
    Truck_No: "ZB001"
  },
  {
    Shippment_out: "2020-05-11",
    Batch: "B001",
    Truck_No: "ZB002"
  },
  {
    Shippment_out: "2020-05-11",
    Batch: "B002",
    Truck_No: "ZB002"
  }
];

const sortArray = (arr, batch) => {
  return arr.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.Batch === batch && b.Batch === batch) {
      return new Date(a.Shippment_out) - new Date(b.Shippment_out);
    } else if (a.Batch === batch) {
      return -1;
    } else if (b.Batch === batch) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  });
};

console.log('B001', sortArray(my_array, "B001"));
console.log('B002', sortArray(my_array, "B002"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can design your sort function like this:

```
items.sort(function(a, b) {
     return a.Batch - b.Batch  ||  a.Shippment_out - b.Shippment_out;
});
```

Here is the logic: if a.Batch - b.Batch expression evaluates to 0 (so these properties are equal), it will proceed with evaluating || expression - and return the result of a.Shippment_out - b.Shippment_out.

Comment: this way returns the array same way also parameter not considered, i've tried this way before. actually this is what i did before.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the important fields to sort them. Just concatenate batch string with date string like `B00120200511` before the comparations inside your sort function.

Edit: To solve your prioritization batch problem, concatenate them with '0' string.

#### Code with your array and a function to sort it with optional batch priorization

```js
var my_array = [
  {
    "Shippment_out": "2020-05-10",
    "Batch": "B001",
    "Truck_No": "ZB001"
  },
  {
    "Shippment_out": "2020-05-10",
    "Batch": "B002",
    "Truck_No": "ZB001"
  },
  {
    "Shippment_out": "2020-05-11",
    "Batch": "B001",
    "Truck_No": "ZB002"
  },
  {
    "Shippment_out": "2020-05-11",
    "Batch": "B002",
    "Truck_No": "ZB002"
  },
];

/**
 * function to sort any array with .Batch and .Shippment_out fields and optionally prioritization of a Batch option
 * @param {Array} arr An array with fields arr.Batch and arr.Shippment_out
 * @param {String} priority Optional field used if you want to prioritize a Batch in the sort
 */
const sortMyArray = (arr, priority = '') => arr.sort((a, b) => {
  // First: concat strings batch with shippment date
  const a_id = (a.Batch === priority ? '0' : a.Batch) + a.Shippment_out;
  const b_id = (b.Batch === priority ? '0' : b.Batch) + b.Shippment_out;

  // Second: compares the new Id with important data to sort
  return a_id >= b_id ? 1 : -1;
});

// to use, just call sortMyArray. You can call with batch priorization
const result1 = sortMyArray(my_array, 'B002');
console.log(result1);
// or without batch priorization
const result2 = sortMyArray(my_array);
console.log(result2);
```

Comment: Still not able to sort with parameter

Comment: @Eliteuser I have improved my solve with "sort with parameter" feature, look at it :)